# Yii2 combine assets into one css and js

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a site based on the advanced app template, everything works fine except I want to combine all the css and js files into one.

So I read [the official documentation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-assets.md) in order to combine assets.

The problem:

- the bootstrap's js file in unminified and is included separately but the css file is compressed and combined perfectly (with the others)?
- how can I combine the assets included with a widget?

Here is my assets.php (which is used with the php yii asset command)

```
Yii::setAlias('@webroot', __DIR__ . '/frontend/web');
Yii::setAlias('@web', '/');

return [
    // Adjust command/callback for JavaScript files compressing:
    'jsCompressor' => 'java -jar compiler.jar --js {from} --js_output_file {to}',
    // Adjust command/callback for CSS files compressing:
    'cssCompressor' => 'yui-compressor --type css {from} -o {to}',
    // The list of asset bundles to compress:
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        'frontend\assets\AppAsset',
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        '\rmrevin\yii\fontawesome\AssetBundle',
    ],
    // Asset bundle for compression output:
    'targets' => [
        'all' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\AssetBundle',
            'basePath' => '@webroot',
            'baseUrl' => '@web',
            'js' => 'js/all-{hash}.js',
            'css' => 'css/all-{hash}.css',
        ],
    ],
    // Asset manager configuration:
    'assetManager' => [
        'basePath' => '@webroot/assets',
        'baseUrl' => '@web/assets',
    ],
];
```

Comment: got this working?